# what is ol.control.Control.call means?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

what's the following code snippet(ol.control.Control.call ) means?  I'm using openlayer 3 to create some buttons on layer.

```
        var options = opt_options || {};
        var element = document.createElement('div');
        element.className = 'ol-unselectable ol-mycontrol';
        element.appendChild(drawPolygon);            

        ol.control.Control.call(this, {
            element: element,
            target: options.target
        });
```

Comment: It means "Access the property `control` on variable `ol`. Then access the property `Control` on the result returned in the previous step. Then access property `call` on the result returned in the previous step. Call that value as a function passing the value of `this` and an object as arguments.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code snippet is incomplete. Is should look like:

```
var MyCustomControl = function(opt_options) {
    var options = opt_options || {};
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.className = 'ol-unselectable ol-mycontrol';
    element.appendChild(drawPolygon);            

    ol.control.Control.call(this, {
        element: element,
        target: options.target
    });
};
ol.inherits(MyCustomControl, ol.control.Control);
```

`MyCustomControl` is the constructor of your custom control, which must inherit the ol base control prototype, which is `ol.control.Control`. To ensure that your custom control is inheriting the ol base control prototype, it is necessary to call the constructor of `ol.control.Control` in the constructor of you custom control, applied to your custom control. In javascript you do it using the `call` method, passing `this` (which represent the custom control you are constructing) as the first argument, and  some other arguments specific to the `ol.control.Control` constructor.

After that, in ol, you call `ol.inherits` to make your custom control inherit `ol.control.Control` methods (http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.html#.inherits).

Comment: Thank  you so much.